# jquery - switch javascript file in head

Tags: jquery

I'm learning jquery and I have a method that I want to implement. I want to test out switch between multiple JS files on one HTML page. So, I want to be able to click a link on the HTML page which will then load another JS script. I've done this so far:

```
$("#jswitch-1").click(function() {
$('head').append('<script src="js/my-jquery-1.js" type="text/javascript"></script>');});
```

jswitch-1 is the id of an HTML link. This method works but I can't see it added to the source code when I view source. Will I also need to remove the current JS file with this function and then load the next one? Or is there another more efficient way of doing this?

Comment: jquery has getscript which automatically adds to head section , try to use that if possible http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getScript/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Viewing source will always show the source, as fetched from the webserver.

If you want to view a serialization of the current state of the DOM, then you will need a DOM Inspector. [Firebug](http://getfirebug.com/) has a good one (for Firefox), Opera has [Dragonfly](http://www.opera.com/dragonfly/), and other browsers tend to have them built in.

That said, you should probably be using [getScript](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getScript/) anyway.

> Will I also need to remove the current JS file with this function and then load the next one?

So long as you override every function, there shouldn't be any issues but watch out for race conditions and event handlers holding copies of previous versions of the functions.

Comment: out of context question , i found a way to add question as favorite , but how can i see all questions under my favorites , do we have any called addtomyfavorites in stackoverflow

Comment: +1 for reference to `getScript()` - a very handy little function!

Comment: i linked my account to meta , but i added one question as favorite and i coulnd't see that anywhere

Comment: I'll rephrase: Let's not clutter up the comments on this question with off-topic discussion about how the site works. Ask your question on meta instead.